# How to submit a form with AJAX and return a summary of the input values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, multipartform-data

I have a multipart form and am using the jQuery form plugin.

When a user completes a section of the form and clicks "continue," I would like to send that information to the server and then provide a summary of the submitted information on the same page. With my current code, I get an error unless all of the fields are completed before submission. My guess is that my PHP is completely wrong and that the information I have entered after "data:" is also incorrect.

Any suggestions on how to make this work properly?

PHP:

```
$return['message'] = array(); 

if ($_POST['markName1']) {
$return['message'][]='Text' . $_POST['markName1'];
}

if ($_POST['markDescription1']) {
$return['message'][]='More text' . $_POST['markDescription1'];
}

 if ($_POST['YesNo1']) {
$return['message'][]='' . $_POST['YesNo1'];
}

echo json_encode($return);
```

jQuery:

```
$(form).ajaxSubmit({                
   type: "POST",
   data: {
          "markName1" : $('#markName1').val(),
          "markDescription1" : $('#markDescription1').val()
                       },
   dataType: 'json',
   url: './includes/ajaxtest3.php',
 //...
   error: function() {alert("error!");},                    
   success: $('#output2').html(data.message.join('<br />'))
//...
```

HTML:

```
<form id="mark-form">
 <div class="markSelection">
    <input type="checkbox" >
      <label for="standardCharacter"></label>
              <span class="markName-field field">
                <label for="markName1" ></label>
                <input type="text" name="markName1" id="markName1">
              </span>   
         <label for="markDescription1"></label>
         <textarea id="markDescription1" name="markDescription1"></textarea>
       <ul class="YesNo">
         <li>
           <input type="radio" name="YesNo1" value="Yes">
             <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
         </li>
         <li>
           <input type="radio" name="YesNo1" value="No">
           <label for="No">No</label>
         </li>
       </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="step-section">
    <p>
    <span class="next-step">
      <button id="submit-second" class="submit" type="submit" name="next">Next</button>
    </span>
   </p>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: there is JQuery's http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post that uses a short hand method and now has .succes(fn), .error(fn), etc... and an awesome podcast by http://doctype.tv/jquery15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need quotes around this `markName1:$('#markName1').val()` or `markDescription1 : $('#markDescription1').val()`

Try putting this for your success callback

```
success: function(html) {
        alert(html);
    }
```

You should change your PHP to this:

```
$markName1 = $_POST['markName1'];
$markDescription1 = $_POST['markDescription1'];
$YesNo1 = $_POST['YesNo1'];

if(!empty($markName1)){
echo 'Text' . $markName1;
}
if(!empty($markDescription1)){
echo 'More Text' . $markDescription1;
}
if(!empty($YesNo1)){
echo $YesNo1;
}
```

**Note** I changed the success function data type to html

**EDIT 2**

create a button outside the `<form>` and replace your ajax with this:

```
$('#submit-button').click(function() {
    $.post('./includes/ajaxtest3.php', $('#mark-form').serialize(), function(html) {
        document.getElementById('someDiv').write(html);
    }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. When I changed the callback as you suggested, I received the following alert: "[object Object]"

Comment: @Ken try puttin `data` instead of `json` in that function

Comment: @Trevor Arjeski I've changed json to data but I'm still getting "[object Object]."

Comment: @Ken hmm...do you need to return a json? can't you just return some html that prints the message from the array?

Comment: @Trevor Arjeski Don't know for sure that I need json (I'm new to all of this). But the only way I seem to be able to get things to work is if I fill in every field listed in the PHP. Otherwise, I get an error.

Comment: @Ken and if you want to use a simpler way to submit form data let me know and I'll re-edit

Comment: @Trevor Arjeski Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work either. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: @Ken do you have a button to submit the form?

Comment: @Trevor Arjeski Yes (added to my code above). The code as I have it works fine if all the fields are entered and submitted, but fails if not all fields are filled in.

Comment: Doesn't that completely alter things? I'm using the form plugin and the validate plugin. And I want to manipulate the info coming back from the server.

Comment: "When a user completes a section of the form and clicks "continue," I would like to send that information to the server and then provide a summary of the submitted information on the same page." That's all I thought you wanted

Comment: I apologize for not being more clear in my question. I essentially just want to display the info submitted within a new div. But I'm also wondering why my current code requires that all fields be submitted in order to work.

Comment: @Ken The code you have shouldn't require all fields to be submitted.  All fields are submitted in the form, but it is up to you in your PHP whether you want to output the fields.  Look closely at the php example I provided:  The fields are only output if they are filled, hence the "if is not empty".  If the field is empty it simply skips over the output of that field.

Comment: @Trevor Arjeski Thanks for the help! I wasn't properly using !empty. All seems to be working now.

Comment: @Ken Nice! I'm glad.  Hope all goes well with the rest of the project